# Keyboard problem with combining accents and letters

Tags: keyboard, compose-key

I'm using a Swedish keyboard with which I use to write Italian text as well. Until less than a week ago it was possible to use the following characters ´ ` ^ ~ on top of other characters, I mean: before you typed one of them and it didn't show up if you didn't typed another key. Since one of the latest updates, (I can't say which,) it's impossible to use those characters in this way, that is when I type one of them it appears on the screen instead of waiting for the character it should be on top (i.e. if I need to write perché in Italian using the sequence ´ + e what I get is ´e).

Note it works fine when I type in a command line in Terminal.

Comment: I don't have the details, but look for a setting like `Compose` or `Compose key` in the keyboard settings.